# How to generate trace ID in AWS format

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, open-telemetry

I would like to use [opentelemetry-java-instrumentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation) with AWS OTEL collector and X-Ray. Unfortunately, AWS OTEL aws-xray exporter is not able to export generated traces to X-Ray because generated trace ID is invalid X-Ray trace ID:

```
awsxrayexporter@v0.36.0/awsxray.go:65   Error translating span. {"kind": "exporter", "name": "awsxray", "error": "invalid xray traceid: 285a8d7e2694ae62bdb3dff2eed5ae41"}
```

How to instrument my opentelemetry-java-instrumentation 1.7.0 to generate trace IDs in X-Ray format?

I've tried to add aws extension + env variables:

```
OTEL_PROPAGATORS: xray,tracecontext,b3
OTEL_JAVAAGENT_EXTENSIONS: /path/opentelemetry-extension-aws-1.7.0.jar
```

without success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, AWS maintains own [a redistribution of the OpenTelemetry Agent for Java](https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-java-instrumentation/), which is customized for AWS services (X-Ray included).

Comment: Did the aws distro java agent work? I'm using that but still the traceid generated by opentelemetry and the one that is pushed into aws xray are different. Here I'm trying to do trace injection and because the traceId being injected in logs and the xray trace is different, traces and logs are getting linked.